# push "dhcp-option DNS <hostname>"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, openvpn

I got a raspberry pi up and running with docker.

I have a container which contains a pi-hole (ad blocker) and I would like to point my DNS query to it.

So I got an OpenVPN container which configuration is :

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 172.200.0.10"
```

But for it to be working, I have to declare a network and fix an ip address (in this case 172.200.0.10) in my docker-compose file.

I would like to do something more elegant like :

```
push "dhcp-option DNS pihole"
```

Is it possible?

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  pihole:
    image: diginc/pi-hole-multiarch:debian_armhf
    container_name: pihole
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "80:80/tcp"
    environment:
      ServerIP: ****
      PROXY_LOCATION: pihole
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ****
      VIRTUAL_PORT: ****
      WEBPASSWORD: ****
    extra_hosts:
      - "****:****"
    networks:
      public:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.10
      private:
        ipv4_address: 172.200.0.10 # To be set in openvpn.conf as push "dhcp-option DNS 172.200.0.10"
    restart: always
  openvpn:
    image: mjenz/rpi-openvpn
    container_name: openvpn
    ports:
      - "1194:1194/udp"
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    links:
      - "pihole:pihole"
    volumes:
      - "/etc/openvpn-data/conf:/etc/openvpn"
    networks:
      public:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.11
      private:
        ipv4_address: 172.200.0.11
    restart: always
    networks:
      public:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.12
      private:
        ipv4_address: 172.200.0.12
  restart: always
networks:
  public:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.100.0.0/16
  private:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.200.0.0/16
```

PS: I got a link to pihole in my docker file and ping pihole works in my openVPN container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`links` is a legacy feature and will be removed in the future. Use `depends_on` instead.

In your example:

```
version: "3"
services:
  pihole:
    ...
  openvpn:
    depends_on:
    - pihole
    ...
```

Then, in the openVPN container you can refer to your pihole container by using the name `pihole`.

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on